# How can I hide the line numbers in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How can I hide left lines counting thing in Notepad++?

I can't find it in menu and can't google it. I don't like it.

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer true for the latest version of Notepad++. See [766024resu's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1634682/144476).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This option controls the visibility of line numbers:
**Settings** → **Preferences** → **Editing**

[image]

Comment: Ok. But why it is in the "editing" tab? I searched in General, Misc and View menu.

Comment: @Qiao: Sorry, I don't know why it was put there.

Comment: This is no longer true for the latest version. See [766024resu's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1634682/144476).

Answer (score 10):

I'm on version 7.9.2 and the answer is slighly different than @Der Hochstapler's answer from 2012.

For version 7.9.2 and later go to Settings → Preferences → Margins/Border/Edge and there's an option to display Line Number as shown:

[image: Margins/Border/Edge pic]

Also, I was going to add this as a comment but since I don't have 50 reputation it's now an answer. I do not even have enough rep to display the image above, you'll just have to click it.

Comment: Why it this has been downvoted?

Comment: @Toto Makes no sense that it has, the accepted answer will not work for anyone who downloads the program for the first time or updates to the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Status Bar displayed when your doc is open, select the View tab and uncheck Line Numbers and the numbers should no longer display. Short cut would be to click on your doc, then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> keys  to toggle between numbers and no numbers.

Comment: For me, that inserts an [SO] character

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to hide/display the status bar.  The line counting on this element may be what is bothering you if you've already figured out how to hide the line-number column.

Comment: nope, I just confused words "counting" and "numbers"